# What is the equivalent of timestamp (%d) in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, timestamp, delphi-7, executable

I want to run an application with a timestamp as parameter. In C, I use something like that:

```
char startCommand[64];
sprintf_s(startCommand, 64, "l2.bin %d", time(NULL));
HANDLE hProcess = CreateProcess( NULL, startCommand, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi );
```

Is it possible to add a timestamp parameter in this Delphi code?

```
var
  Play : string;
  Par : string;
begin
  Play := 'myfile.exe';
  Par := '??'; // the parameter - Timestamp
  ShellExecute(TForm(Owner).Handle, nil, PChar(Play), PChar(Par), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

Do I have to do `DateTimeToStr` first?

Answer (score 4):

The C `time()` function "returns the time since the Epoch (00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970), measured in seconds".  You can use Delphi's `DateUtils.SecondsBetween()` function to get a similar value, eg:

```
uses
  ..., Windows, DateUtils;

function CTime: Int64;
var
  SystemTime: TSystemTime;
  LocalTime, UTCTime: TFileTime;
  NowUTC, EpochUTC: TDateTime;
begin
  // get Jan 1 1970 UTC as a TDateTime...
  DateTimeToSystemTime(EncodeDate(1970, 1, 1), SystemTime);
  if not SystemTimeToFileTime(SystemTime, LocalTime) then RaiseLastOSError;
  if not LocalFileTimeToFileTime(LocalTime, UTCTime) then RaiseLastOSError;
  if not FileTimeToSystemTime(UTCTime, SystemTime) then RaiseLastOSError;
  EpochUTC := SystemTimeToDateTime(SystemTime);

  // get current time in UTC as a TDateTime...
  GetSystemTime(SystemTime);
  with SystemTime do
    NowUTC := EncodeDateTime(wYear, wMonth, wDay, wHour, wMinute, wSecond, wMilliseconds);

  // now calculate the difference in seconds...
  Result := SecondsBetween(NowUTC, EpochUTC);
end;
```

Alternatively, you can use the `DateUtils.DateTimeToUnix()` function:

```
uses
  ..., Windows, DateUtils;

function CTime: Int64;
var
  SystemTime: TSystemTime;
  NowUTC: TDateTime;
begin
  // get current time in UTC as a TDateTime...
  GetSystemTime(SystemTime);
  with SystemTime do
    NowUTC := EncodeDateTime(wYear, wMonth, wDay, wHour, wMinute, wSecond, wMilliseconds);

  // now calculate the difference from Jan 1 1970 UTC in seconds...
  Result := DateTimeToUnix(NowUTC);
end;
```

Either way, you can then do this:

```
var
  Play : string;
  Par : string;
begin
  Play := 'myfile.exe';
  Par := IntToStr(CTime());
  ShellExecute(TForm(Owner).Handle, nil, PChar(Play), PChar(Par), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

Or, using `CreateProcess()` instead, similar to what the C code is doing:

```
var
  startCommand : string;
  hProcess: THandle;
  si: TStartupInfo;
  pi: TProcessInformation;
begin
  startCommand := Format('%s %d', ['myfile.exe', CTime()]);
  ...
  ZeroMemory(@si, sizeof(si));
  si.cb := sizeof(si);
  si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  si.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(startCommand), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, si, pi) then
  begin
    hProcess := pi.hProcess;
    ...
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

`time(NULL)` returns time elapsed in seconds since 01/01/1970 UTC (Unix time)

You can convert TDateTime into needed format using [DateUtils.DateTimeToUnix](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.DateUtils.DateTimeToUnix)